# Matplotlib doesn't plot correct graph and its scales

Tags: python, html, pyscript

I heard about pyscript a few weeks about
And i learned basic things
I want the user to enter the data in input elements and title xaxis and yaxis
And to select the type bar line or pie etc
Here's the code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as p
def run(*args , **kwargs):
    t1 = Element("te1").value
    t2 = Element("te2").value
    t3 = Element("te3").value
    t4 = Element("te4").value
    t5 = Element("te5").value
    t6 = Element("te6").value
    t7 = Element("te7").value
    t8 = Element("te8").value
    t9 = Element("te9").value
    t10 = Element("te10").value
    title = Element("title").value
    xl = Element("xl").value 
    yl = Element("yl").value 
    p.title(title)
    p.xlabel(xl)
    p.ylabel(yl)
    x = np.array([t1,t2,t3,t4,t5])
    y = np.array([t6,t7,t8,t9,t10])
    cs = np.array(["darkorange","deeppink","#04aa6d","orchid","dodgerblue"])
    if Element("selection").value == "line":
        p.plot(x,y)
    elif Element("selection").value == "scatter":
        p.scatter(x,y)
    elif Element("selection").value == "barg":
        p.bar(x,y , color=cs)
    elif Element("selection").value == "":
        p.plot(x,y)
    else:
        p.pie(y, labels=x)      
        p.legend()
    pyscript.write("res",p)
```

And the button

```
<button id="sub" pys-onClick="run">Submit</button>
```

The input elements

```
<div id="table1" >
<input type="number" id="te1" placeholder="enter a no." value="1" >
<input type="number" id="te2" placeholder="enter a no." value="2" >
<input type="number" id="te3" placeholder="enter a no." value="3" >
<input type="number" id="te4" placeholder="enter a no." value="4" >
<input type="number" id="te5" placeholder="enter a no." value="5" >
</div>
```

```
<input type="number" id="te6" placeholder="enter a no." value="48"  >
<input type="number" id="te7" placeholder="enter a no." value="53"  >
<input type="number" id="te8" placeholder="enter a no." value="60"  >
<input type="number" id="te9" placeholder="enter a no." value="68"  >
<input type="number" id="te10" placeholder="enter a no." value="72"  >
```

```
<option value="" selected disabled >Select ( Graph / Chart ) Type</option>
<option value="line" >Line Graph</option>
<option value="scatter" >Scattered Graph</option>
<option value="barg" >Bar Graph</option>
<option value="pie" >Pie Chart</option>
```

Output

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cp9oZ.jpg)

But when i run this python code on pydriod
It returns correct graph
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBsiV.jpg)

Comment: Can you clarify the problem? I have reviewed both graphs. What is the issue?

Comment: See the y - axis scale and the differences between the scale points

Comment: In the first pic the line is starlight but see the another pic's graph its totally different

Comment: The data given to both graphs is same